# what is the simplest way to create a table use django db api ,and base on 'Standalone Django scripts'

Tags: python, django

we can call this 'Standalone Django table'

i am not successful  now .

can you ???

thanks

if you don't know 'Standalone Django scripts', look this  http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

---

2.this is my code:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from sphinx_test import settings

setup_environ(settings)

import sys
sys.path.append('D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test')


from django.db import models
from djangosphinx.models import SphinxSearch,SphinxQuerySet



class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    objects = models.Manager()
    search  = SphinxQuerySet(index="test1")
    #class Meta:#<-----------  1
    #    app_label = 'sphinx_test'#<------ 2
```

and my problem is when i add '#' in front of 1 and 2,it's error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test\books\models.py", line 17, in <module>
    class File(models.Model):
  File "D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 52, in __new__
    kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

when i remove '#' in front of 1 and 2,it print nothing,and don't create table yet.

why ??

Comment: You're going to have to show your code here or they won't know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked is a pretty damn good explanation of the simplest way to do it.

**Edit:** Re-arranged this for clarity.

Starting with a fresh app, create a model, sync the database to create the tables, and then use the `setup_environ` function from within your standalone script.

Of course this is assuming that `myapp` is in your `PYTHONPATH`. If it isn't you must append the path to your app before try to import it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from django.core.management import setup_environ

# If myapp is not in your PYTHONPATH, append it to sys.path
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/myapp/')

# This must be AFTER you update sys.path
from myapp import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from myapp.models import Foo, Bar

# do stuff
foo = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
bar = Bar.objects.filter(foo=foo.baz)
```

**Edit #2:** In response to the updated code by the OP. You are trying to create a new model from within the standalone script, which is not the right approach. A standalone script should not be used to create new models or applications, but rather to reference already existing data.

So using your example you would need to create a new app from within a project and then create another script to use as the standalone script.  So I'll use the creation of `standalone.py` as an example.

This is what file structure of `D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test` should look like:

```
sphinx_test
|-- __init__.py
|-- manage.py
|-- settings.py
`-- urls.py
```

So first you would need to create a new app from within this project folder.  Let's call it `file_test` and create it with `python manage.py startapp file_test`. Now the file tree of `D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test` should look like this:

```
sphinx_test
|-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.pyc
|-- file_test
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- manage.py
|-- settings.py
|-- settings.pyc
`-- urls.py
```

Now you can create your `File` model in `file_test\models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from djangosphinx.models import SphinxSearch,SphinxQuerySet

class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    objects = models.Manager()
    search  = SphinxQuerySet(index="test1")
    #class Meta:#<-----------  1
    #    app_label = 'sphinx_test'#<------ 2
```

After you create this model, this is where you would execute `python manage.py syncdb` to create the model tables in the database you have configured for this app.

Then you can create `standalone.py` that has all the logic to work with the `file_test.models.File` model you just created:

```
#!/path/to/python
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import sys
sys.path.append('D:\zjm_code\sphinx_test')

from sphinx_test import settings
setup_environ(settings)

# NOW you can import from your app
from sphinx_test.file_test.models import File

f = File(name='test', tags='abc,xyz,', search='foo')
f.save()

# confirm the data was saved
if f.id:
    print 'success!'
else:
    print 'fail!'
```

You have now created a standalone script that can interact with the Django ORM without need for a webserver or a testserver instance running.  This is why it is considered to be standalone, because the new script you created may be executed at the command-line alone.

Comment: 'myapp.models' is a py file or a file which made by 'python manage.py startapp models'  ???