# How to import data from scanned text into Django models

Tags: python, django, import

I have a hundreds of pages of "quiz" questions, multiple-choice options and associated answer keys and explanations. I'm trying to create a simple Django app to administer these questions. I have created a simple but effective Python parser to parse the scanned, OCR'd pages into the proper objects.

I want to have a "utility" to enable the administrator of this Django app to import quiz content from OCR'd paper into the relevant Django DB tables. This will be a rare task, and something that is not necessarily appropriate for inclusion in a web UI.

I've asked about using intermediate JSON/YAML fixtures and was told that a more appropriate approach would be to directly create and save instances of my models [1]. I then tried to create a standalone script along the lines suggested by [2] and [3] but was unable to overcome the 
`kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range` 
error.

I also came across [4] about creating custom django-admin.py/manage.py commands. This seems like a logically appropriate way of dealing with the task; but, I'd love to hear from those with more experience and brains (I've eaten all mine :).

### References:

1. [Importing data from scanned text into Django as YAML fixture or SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669550/importing-data-from-scanned-text-into-django-as-yaml-fixture-or-sql)
2. [what is the simplest way to create a table use django db api ,and base on 'Standalone Django scripts'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211816/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-create-a-table-use-django-db-api-and-base-on-stand)
3. [Standalone Scripts](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/)
4. [Writing custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

### Examples:

- OCR'd Text

> Page 12
>   34. Hiedegger is a _____ . (a) philosopher (b) boozy beggar (c) both a and b (d) none of these 35. ...

- Django Models

  ```
  class Question(models.Model):
      text = models.TextField()
  class Choice(models.Model):
      question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
      order = models.IntegerField(default=1)
      text = models.TextField()
  ```
- Goal, something like this...

  ```
  q = Question.objects.create(text="Hiedegger is a _____ .")
  q.save()
  c = Choice(text="philosopher", order=1, question=q.pk)
  c.save()
  ```

Comment: for my standalone web crawling script I have created a custom admin command which populates the database by directly manipulating the models.

Comment: Thanks. I'm playing with that approach right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working version I came up with. Dirty, but effective. Both @akonsu and @Ivan Kharlamov were helpful. Thanks...

```
import os, re, Levenshtein as lev, codecs
from SimpleQuiz.quiz.models import Choice, Question
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import optparse

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '--datapath=/path/to/text/data/'
    can_import_settings = True
    help = 'Imports scanned text into Questions and Choices'
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        optparse.make_option('--datapath', action='store', type='string',
                             dest='datapath',
                             help='Path to OCRd text files to be parsed.'),
        )
    requires_model_validation = True
    # Parser REs
    BACKUP_RE = re.compile(r'\~$|bak$|back$|backup$')
    QUEST_RE = re.compile(r'^[0-9]{1,3}[.][ ]')
    CHOICE_RE = re.compile(r'^[a-e][.][ ]')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # get the data path
        try:
            os.path.exists(options['datapath'])
        except Exception as e:
            raise CommandError("None or invalid path provided: %s" % e.message)
        self.datapath = os.path.expanduser(options['datapath'])

        # generate list of text strings from lines in target files
        self.data_lines = []
        for fn in os.listdir(os.path.join(self.datapath, 'questions/')):
            if self.BACKUP_RE.search(fn):
                self.stderr.write("Skipping backup: %s\n" % (fn))
            else:
                for line in codecs.open(os.path.join(self.datapath, 'questions/', fn), 'r', encoding='latin-1'):
                    if not self.is_boilerplate(line):
                        if not line.strip() == '':
                            self.data_lines.append(line)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    #--------------------- Parse the text lines and create Questions/Choices
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        cur_quest = None
        cur_choice = None
        cur_is_quest = False
        questions = {}
        choices = {}
        for line in self.data_lines:
            if self.is_question(line):
                [n, txt] = line.split('.', 1)
                qtext = txt.rstrip() + " "
                q = Question.objects.create(text=qtext)
                q.save()
                cur_quest = q.pk
                questions[cur_quest] = q
                cur_is_quest = True
            elif self.is_choice(line):
                [n, txt] = line.split('.', 1)
                num = self.char2dig(n)
                ctext = txt.rstrip() + " "
                c = Choice.objects.create(text=ctext, order=num, question=questions[cur_quest])
                c.save()
                cur_choice = c.pk
                choices[cur_choice] = c
                cur_is_quest = False
            else:
                if cur_is_quest:
                    questions[cur_quest].text += line.rstrip() + " "
                    questions[cur_quest].save()
                else:
                    choices[cur_choice].text += line.rstrip() + " "
                    choices[cur_choice].save()
        self.stdout.write("----- FINISHED -----\n")
        return None

    def is_question(self, arg_str):
        if self.QUEST_RE.search(arg_str):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def is_choice(self, arg_str):
        if self.CHOICE_RE.search(arg_str):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def char2dig(self, x):
        if x == 'a':
            return 1
        if x == 'b':
            return 2
        if x == 'c':
            return 3
        if x == 'd':
            return 4
        if x == 'e':
            return 5

    def is_boilerplate(self, arg_str):
        boilerplate = [u'MFT PRACTICE EXAMINATIONS',
                       u'BERKELEY TRAINING ASSOCIATES ' + u'\u00A9' + u' 2009',
                       u'BERKELEY TRAINING ASSOCIATES',
                       u'MARRIAGE AND FAMILY THERAPY',
                       u'PRACTICE EXAMINATION 41',
                       u'Page 0', u'Page 1', u'Page 2', u'Page 3', u'Page 4',
                       u'Page 5', u'Page 6', u'Page 7', u'Page 8', u'Page 9',
                       ]
        for bp in boilerplate:
            if lev.distance(bp.encode('utf-8'), arg_str.encode('utf-8')) < 4:
                return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

> I then tried to create a standalone script along the lines suggested
>   by [2] and [3] but was unable to overcome the kwargs = {"app_label":
>   model_module.**name**.split('.')[-2]} IndexError: list index out of
>   range error.

I had the same list index error. It was caused by the way I imported the models in my script. I used to do it like this:

```
from models import Table1, Table2
```

Then I realized the Python script is not part of the application, so I changed the import to:

```
from myapp.models import Table1, Table2
```

My Python script is started with the following shell script:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my/site
python myscript.py "$@"
```